# PHP hours and minutes between two times

Tags: php

```
$time1 = "14:45";
$time2 = "15:55";
list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $time1);
$startTimestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes);

list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $time2);
$endTimestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes);

$seconds = $endTimestamp - $startTimestamp;
$minutes = ($seconds / 60) % 60;
$hours = round($seconds / (60 * 60));

echo "<b>$hours</b> hours and<b>$minutes</b> minutes</b>";
```

This code works good if the variable time1 is lower than variable time2, but if the time1 is "23:35" and time2 is "01:40" it will output  "-22 hours and -55 minutes".

How can I correct this so it still will output the hours and minutes between the both times even if the time1 is lower than time2 variable

*This code will take two times example "14:45" and "16:33" and calculate how many hours and minutes it is between each time, but it doesn't work if "time1" is lower than "time2" (time1 and time2 is variables)*

http://codepad.org/QmFdN6RV

Comment: use ABS() function applied to the substraction

Comment: That depends on if 23:35 is one day, and 01:40 is the next, of if it is the same day.

Comment: 23:35 would be one day and 01:40 would be the early morning of the other day

Comment: @LuisSiquot How could I do that?, doesnt the ABS just get rid of the "-"?

Comment: You have to give dates then, one day greater than the other, otherwise you're only getting the number of seconds between two times on the same day.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I would do it, using [**strtotime()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
// If dates are not specified, strtotime() will assume both are from today
$time1 = "23:45";
$time2 = "01:24";

// Absolute value of time difference in seconds
$diff = abs(strtotime($time1) - strtotime($time2));

// Convert $diff to minutes
$tmins = $diff/60;

// Get hours
$hours = floor($tmins/60);

// Get minutes
$mins = $tmins%60;
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/cBXOYAUX)

This assumes that `$time1` and `$time2` are from the same day. If not, then this will need to be specified.

```
$time1 = "today 23:45";
$time2 = "tomorrow 01:24";
// or
$time1 = "2014-7-3 23:45";
$time2 = "2014-7-4 01:24";
// or some other method of specifying the day.
```

[**See demo 2**](http://codepad.org/cQ2RB5Gg)

Comment: The time between those two times should be  1h39m, not 22h21m

Comment: @HannesBrolinLagerstedt There has to be some way of clarifying which day the time comes from. See my update.

Comment: @HannesBrolinLagerstedt Is the order of the times always the same? i.e. is `$time2` always greater than `$time1`?

Answer (score 2):

So dont know what you really want as result - could be two ways, so i do both ;)

you have also to use floor and not round.

First solution is, that you get the difference based on same day:

```
<?php
$time1 = "23:45";
$time2 = "01:44";
list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $time1);
$firstTimestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes);

list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $time2);
$secondTimestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes);

$firstTimestamp > $secondTimestamp?$seconds = $firstTimestamp - $secondTimestamp:$seconds = $secondTimestamp - $firstTimestamp;

$minutes = ($seconds / 60) % 60;
$hours = floor($seconds / (60 * 60));

echo "<b>$hours</b> hours and <b>$minutes</b> minutes</b>";
?>
```

output would be: **22** hours and **1** minutes

the second way is, that the endtime (named it secondtime) is the next day
than it should be like

```
<?php
$time1 = "23:45";
$time2 = "01:24";
list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $time1);
$firstTimestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes);

list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $time2);
$secondTimestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes);

$seconds =  $secondTimestamp - $firstTimestamp;

$seconds<0?$seconds+=24*60*60:"";

$minutes = ($seconds / 60) % 60;
$hours = floor($seconds / (60 * 60));


echo "<b>$hours</b> hours and <b>$minutes</b> minutes</b>";
?>
```

output would be: **1** hours and **39** minutes

url to codepad: http://codepad.org/7plRAhZJ

Answer (score 1):

if the seconds are negative, add 24 hours to them:

```
$time1 = "23:35";
$time2 = "1:40";  
list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $time1);
$startTimestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes);

list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $time2);
$endTimestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes);

$seconds = $endTimestamp - $startTimestamp;
if($seconds < 0) {
    $seconds+=60*60*24; 
}

$minutes = ($seconds / 60) % 60;
$hours = round($seconds / (60 * 60));

echo "<b>$hours</b> hours and<b>$minutes</b> minutes</b>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `date_diff`

```
$date1 = new DateTime();
$date2 = new DateTime();
$date1->setTimestamp($startTimestamp);
$date2->setTimestamp($endTimestamp);
$interval = date_diff($date1, $date2);
//or $interval = $date1->diff($date2)
echo $interval->format('%h hours and %m minutes');
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do this way:

```php
$time1 = "23:40";
$time2 = "01:40";
list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $time1);
$startTimestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes);

list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $time2);
$endTimestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes);

$seconds = abs($endTimestamp - $startTimestamp);
$diff = (24*60*60)-$seconds;
if ($diff < $seconds) {
    $seconds = $diff;
}

$minutes = ($seconds / 60) % 60; 
$hours = round($seconds / (60 * 60));

echo "<b>$hours</b> hours and<b>$minutes</b> minutes</b>"
```

Note that this will never give you diferences bigger than 12h.

For instance, the difference between 06:00 and 22:00 will be 8 hours